# What's the difference between calling MyClass.class and MyClass.getClass()

Tags: java, reflection

`MyClass.class` and `MyClass.getClass()` both seem to return a `java.lang.Class`. Is there a subtle distinction or can they be used interchangeably? Also, is `MyClass.class` a public property of the superclass `Class` class? (I know this exists but can't seem to find any mention of it in the javadocs)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One is an instance method, so it returns the class of the particular object, the other is a Class constant (i.e. known at compile-time).

```
 Class n = Number.class;
 Number o = 1;
 o.getClass() // returns Integer.class
 o = BigDecimal.ZERO;
 o.getClass();  // returns BigDecimal.class
```

Both cases return instances of the Class object, which describes a particular Java class. For the same class, they return the same instance (there is only one Class object for every class).

A third way to get to the Class objects would be

```
Class n = Class.forName("java.lang.Number");
```

Keep in mind that interfaces also have Class objects (such as Number above).

> Also, is MyClass.class a public property of the superclass Class class?

It is a language keyword.

Comment: What do you mean by a "Class constant"? When you assign "Class n = Number.class;" what would be the value of n?

Comment: n gets assigned an instance of Class, the object with describes the Number "class" (which is actually an interface).

Answer (score 5):

`.getClass()` returns the runtime class of the object, so it can be modified when you change the class of the variable

`.class` on the other hand always return the class constant of the "Type"

**NOTE**
If the runtime class happens to be the same as the TYPE class, both will be equal.
Example:

```
Long x = new Long(2);
Class c1 = Long.class;
Class c2 = x.getClass();

//c1==c2
```

Comment: ".class on the other hand always return the class constant of the "Type" -> What does that mean?

Comment: @Mocha `Long` is a type, `new Long(2)` is new object of that type

Answer (score 4):

The MyClass doesn't have a static getClass method, in other words, you cannot call MyClass.getClass(), instead you need to call (new MyClass()).getClass() for it to work.

getClass() will return a MyClass.class object. So in other words, MyClass.class is the resulting object while getClass() is a method. The getClass() method is useful in cases where you do not know the actual class of the object, for example:

```
public void someMethod(Object o) {
   if(o.getClass().equals(Set.class)) {
      // The object is a set
   } else if(o.getClass().equals(List.class)) {
     // The object is a List
   }
}
```

Note that the above code example isn't the best possible, I'm just trying to show how it could be used. The same functionality could be achieved with `if(o instanceof Set)  { ...}`

Answer (score 1):

```
What's the difference between calling MyClass.class and MyClass.getClass()
```

First of all your question title is a bit misleading! `.getClass() is a method defined in java.lang.Object` so any object in java can call it where as .class is called on the class itself(like public static variables). So the question should be (sticking to java naming conventions)

```
What's the difference between calling MyClass.class and myClassObject.getClass()
```

Now to actual differences

.getClass() is a native java method in java.lang.Object. This method will return java.lang.Class object corresponding to the `runtime class` of the object on which it is invoked. So

```
    Test t = new TestSubClass();
    Class c2 = t.getClass();
    System.out.println(c2);
```

will print `class TestSubClass`

where as .class will return the statically evaluated (known at compile time) class. It is actually Class object corresponding to the reference type pointing to the actual object.So

```
    Test t = new TestSubClass();
    Class c2 = Test.class;
    System.out.println(c2);
```

will print `class Test`