# Difference between MyClass.class and Class.forName("className")

Tags: java, reflection

We can get class Class object by 3 methods:

- MyClass.class
- obj.getClass
- Class.forName("className")

I don't understood the difference between: `MyClass.class` and `Class.forName("className")`.

Because both will need Class Name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between calling MyClass.class and MyClass.getClass()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467970/whats-the-difference-between-calling-myclass-class-and-myclass-getclass)

Comment: The suggestions or implications made in various answers that MyClass.class doesn't cause a runtime lookup are false. It just causes an *earlier* runtime lookup, when the class containing the reference is loading! and a lookup failure is fatal to that loading.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Class.forName("className");
```

forName is a static method of class "Class".
we require to provide  the fully qualified name of the desired class. 
this can be used when name of class will come to known at runtime.

```
ClassName.class;
```

.class is not a method it is a keyword and can be used with primitive type like int.
when Name of Class is known in advance & it is added to project, that time we use ClassName.class

Comment: or, in short: runtime lookup vs. compile time lookup

Comment: .class is not a keyword.

Answer (score 8):

> I don't understood the difference between: `MyClass.class` and `Class.forName("className")`.
>
> Because both will need Class Name.

The big difference is *when* they need it. Since `Class.forName` accepts a *string*, the class name can be determined at runtime. Whereas of course, `MyClass.class` is determined at compile-time. This makes `Class.forName` useful for dynamically loading classes based on configuration (for instance, loading database drivers depending on the settings of a config file).

Rounding things out: `obj.getClass()` is useful because you may not know the actual class of an object — for instance, in a method where you accept an argument using an interface, rather than class, such as in `foo(Map m)`. You don't know the class of `m`, just that it's something that implements `Map`. (And 99% of the time, you shouldn't care what its class is, but that 1% crops up occasionally.)

Comment: nice explanation

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.forName("className");
```

It dynamically load the class based on fully qualified class name string.

```
obj.getClass
```

Returns the java.lang.Class object that represents the runtime class of the object.

```
MyClass.class:
```

A `class` literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array,
or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by `a`'.' and the token class.
The type of `C.class`, where C is the name of a class, interface, or array type is `Class<C>`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One important difference is:
A.class will perform loading and linking of class A.
Class.forName("A") will perform loading, linking and initialization of class A.