# getclass() vs .class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between calling MyClass.class and MyClass.getClass()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467970/whats-the-difference-between-calling-myclass-class-and-myclass-getclass)

Wanting to have a `Class<T>` object, Which is the difference between these two approaches?

```
Test ob = new Test();

ob.getclass();
```

or

```
Test.class
```

Comment: Duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/2467970/1225328](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2467970/1225328)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Class javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

First approach get **Class** object from `Object`.

second approach get **Class** object for a named type (or for void) using a `class` literal.

Comment: I think it is called as class literal notation. Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2

Comment: Besides the link, your answer really doesn't explain much.

Comment: @PaulBellora: Edited to add some content, apart from that I am not sure what else I could add, If you have anything to add, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Void is special type in java.

Comment: @jacktrades In addition to reference types (including arrays), there are also class literals for each primitive and `void`. These are useful for reflection, for example [`Method.getReturnType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType\(\)) for methods that return primitives or void.

Comment: @jacktrades: See this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352447/what-is-the-need-of-void-class-in-java

Comment: Well, `Void` (capitalized) serves a different purpose from `void.class` (which `Void.TYPE` points to). But yeah, that's a good discussion about it.

Answer (score 5):

The `getClass()` method is defined in `java.lang.Object` and hence can be called on any object reference.

> It gets the Class object associated with the run-time type of the object to which the reference points.
>   .
>
> The getClass() method is not really analogous to .class at all. Closer is Class.forName(String), which gets a Class object for the class named by the String.

In situations where either could be used, use `.class` , as it is more efficient.